# Viewing a PNG image 1 pixel row from the bottom and the right column are missing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, gdi+

Using the code below (called from `CLoadPngDlg::OnPaint()`) to view a PNG file (800X50 pixels) that is already included in the resource (*IDB_FULLSCRINFOBAR_OPAQ_TEST*) file, but as you can see in the attached image the bottom and the right line of the image a missing. I can confirm that `nWidth=800` and `nHeight=50`

```
BOOL CLoadPngDlg::ShowPngAt(CDC *dcWnd) {   

    CGdiPlusBitmapResource      *pPngChannel;
    UINT                        nWidth,nHeight;
    CRect                       rectClient;
    CBitmap                     Bitmap, *pOldBitmap;    
    CDC                         bitmapDC;
    CDC                         *dialogDC;

    pPngChannel = NULL;
    pPngChannel = new CGdiPlusBitmapResource;

    if (!pPngChannel->Load(IDB_FULLSCRINFOBAR_OPAQ_TEST, _T("PNG"))) {
        delete pPngChannel;
        return TRUE;
    }

    GetWindowRect(&rectClient);

    // Get size of bitmap.
    nWidth = pPngChannel->m_pBitmap->GetWidth();
    nHeight = pPngChannel->m_pBitmap->GetHeight();

    bitmapDC.CreateCompatibleDC( dcWnd ); 
    Bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcWnd, nWidth, nHeight);
    pOldBitmap = bitmapDC.SelectObject(&Bitmap);    

    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(bitmapDC.GetSafeHdc());                                      
    graphics.DrawImage(*pPngChannel, 0, 0);

    dcWnd->BitBlt(0, 0, rectClient.Width(), rectClient.Height(), &bitmapDC,   0,  0,   SRCCOPY );

    bitmapDC.SelectObject( pOldBitmap );
    bitmapDC.DeleteDC();


    if (pPngChannel != NULL)
        delete pPngChannel;


    return FALSE;

}
```

[image]

The things are straightforward with a direct copy of the png image inside the client area of the dialog. So, what seems to be the problem here?

**Edit:[SOLVED]** I had to specify the image size inside the DrawImage like this. `graphics.DrawImage(*pPngChannel, 0, 0, nWidth , nHeight);

Comment: Why is `rectClient` the window rect and not the client rect? Shouldn't your call to `dcWnd->BitBlt()` use `nWidth` and `nHeight` as the size to blit?

Comment: Does your system have a display scaling that is not 100%?  You could add some other bars in the image to see how far they move, or if they move.

Comment: Make sure to read about the *"client area"* and *"nonclient area"* under [Application Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows#application-windows).

Comment: @IInspectable I actually need also the nonclient area for a borderless window (full screen)

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I had to specify also the dimension of the PNG image in the DrawImage like this : graphics.DrawImage(*pPngChannel, 0, 0, 800, 50);

Comment: @JonathanPotter You are correct just copied/pasted from a bigger project and I deleted some parts.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, actually I am trying to fix the position of some objects that worked previously with 100% and I have a  problem with scaling factor bigger than 100%. How to deal with this?

Comment: @Maverick Specifying the size in the call to `DrawImage()` should not be necessary (otherwise what's the point of the DrawImage overload that only takes coordinates and not size?)

Comment: @JonathanPotter That's what I thought also, but this trick fixed the problem. Without this in other version of the almost same source returns a double zommed image.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify the image size inside the **DrawImage** like this.

`graphics.DrawImage(*pPngChannel, 0, 0, nWidth , nHeight);`

I tested also this program using different DPI settings. It seems that the clipping problem mentioned, occurs in all low, medium and high DPI settings. So, it is independent from the scaling settings under Windows 10.